# Simulating the Enter key in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, enter

I am trying to simulate a key press in a button event. I can use the code below to simulate some keys such as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but the <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbProdCode.Focus();

    KeyEventArgs ke = new KeyEventArgs(
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
        Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource,
        0,
        Key.Enter)
    {
        RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent
    };

    InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(ke);
}
```

Comment: Something tells me what it is executed too early, not when `tbProdCode` gets focus. Try to put part after setting focus inside `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { ... });`. If it's not the case, then can you please explain what exactly is not working? You have button and textbox, when button is pressed textbox should get focus and ... ?

Comment: I found the problem. Because I used the PreviewKeyDown for btnEnter instead of KeyDown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried your code, and I can simulate the <kbd>Enter</kbd> perfectly.

You've not stated what you wish <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do in your `textbox`, so i'm going to go out on a limb here and assume you want to go to the next line - as that is one of the most common reasons to use `Enter` in a `textbox`

For that to work, you need to set `AcceptsReturn="True"` in `Xaml` - this allows the `textbox` to accept the <kbd>Enter</kbd> Key.

`<TextBox x:Name="tbProdCode" AcceptsReturn="True" />`

If that functionality is not what you want, then you likely don't have an event wired up to do something when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit.

Comment: Might I suggest also putting your `KeyEventArgs ke = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, key)
                      {
                          RoutedEvent = UIElement.KeyDownEvent
                      }; InputManager.Current.ProccessInput(ke)` into it's own function where you pass in a key. i.e. `SendKey(Key key)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is by using Xaml to bind the key press to a command:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```